# Android App won't run in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This question has been asked before but I'm going through the troubleshooting steps I found and it isn't working.

This is the message I see in the console. It is different than usual. The last part cmp=com.quincy.androidbletest/.MonitoringActivity
doesn't seem right.

```
[2014-10-10 17:34:49 - AndroidBLETest] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.quincy.androidbletest/.MonitoringActivity }
```

then when my application opens I see that it has "stopped" on the phone and I get this error:

```
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.quincy.androidbletest.AndroidBLETest: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.quincy.androidbletest.AndroidBLETest" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.quincy.androidbletest-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.quincy.androidbletest-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:507)
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4382)
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1270)
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.quincy.androidbletest.AndroidBLETest" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.quincy.androidbletest-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.quincy.androidbletest-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:998)
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:502)
10-10 17:35:00.833: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    ... 11 more
```

My manifest.xml looks flawless to me:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.quincy.androidbletest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

    <application 
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:name="AndroidBLETest">
        <activity
            android:name="com.quincy.androidbletest.MonitoringActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.quincy.androidbletest.RangingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.quincy.androidbletest.BackgroundActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any help is appreciated. So much issues wow ouch long time working.

Comment: Is it not starting at all? If so, post your `manifest.xml`

Comment: Add all package names before the activity names.for eg:write package name of AndroidBLETest in android:name=".AndroidBLETest" like com.quincy.androidbletest.AndroidBLETest

Comment: yup.. that's what I tried.

Comment: Have you tried `Project → Clean`?

Comment: have you included an activity tag for com.quincy.androidbletest.AndroidBLETest

Comment: still does the same thing :(

Comment: aha. this may be the problem

Comment: I changed the name of the application tag in manifest.xml and I cleaned... still same thing :(

Comment: replace fully qualified package name with android:name=".AndroidBLETest"

Comment: I just put this there: com.quincy.androidbletest.AndroidBLETest

Comment: The problem appears to be with `MonitoringActivity` which is your launching point

Comment: Remove intent filte tag from Ragging and Background Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by switching to Android Studio. Then using gradle 1.10 I was able to build my application and successfully run.

Answer (score 0):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

    <application 
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:name="AndroidBLETest">
        <activity
            android:name="com.quincy.androidbletest.MonitoringActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.quincy.androidbletest.RangingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.quincy.androidbletest.BackgroundActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You should explain *what* you have changed and *why* it should solve the problem instead of posting a block of code

Comment: @DaveHulse I have rolled back your edit. Please don't change the original post. You can edit and add things but please don't change the original or the post will be confusing and useless for future visitors.